# Is it possible using Autodesk Inventor iLogic VBA to create an InputRadioBox that uses information from an existing arraylist in a rule?

Tags: vba, autodesk-inventor

I Have a number of InputListBox's in an iLogic rule that use information from an ArrayList to create an iProperty name and value. This works but the selection list is somewhat bunched together where as an InputRadioBox is much easier not only to read but select from.

My question - is it possible to use an existing ArrayList or to make a List in my rule that an InputRadioBox can use?

My ArrayList's are generally as long as 25 item's, I've tried multiple way's to use my existing ArrayList's to no avail. See below A picture of the InputRadioBox I was able to create along with the code which does not use a list of any kind.

[image: prompt screen]

```
BooleanParam = WCList
WCList = InputRadioBox("Add A WorkCenter", "WC A01 Enginner | Brent" ,"WC C02 Laser/Punch",WCList, Title := "Select Work Center")
```

Comment: InputRadioBox prompts for one of two available options. That's your list limit

Comment: Hi dbmitch, Thank you for your response, I will continue with the ArrayList option.

Comment: Here is answer to similar question https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-ilogic-and-vb-net-forum/creating-temporary-user-parameters-in-a-drawing-for-a-multi/m-p/10689366/highlight/true#M130083

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank You! It looks like the code from the link may accomplish what I've been attempting.